# ExpressJS pode ser usado em produção?

Tags: angularjs, json, express.js

Vi recentemente um curso onde era usado ExpressJS para testes em backend em JSON para uma aplicação e fiquei maravilhado, mas me veio varias perguntas: 
Ele poderia ser usado em produção? 
Pode ser uma alternativa as tecnologias mais usadas atualmente de db e backend?
A performance é boa?
Como ele funciona exatamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que não seria? O Express é uma ótima ferramenta para isso, apesar de existirem opções mais avançadas, como o Sails (que é feito com base no Express).

Se você está começando, use o Express; não haverá nada de mau.
O único porém é o fato de não existir um modelo específico para criar as aplicações, isto é, você pode criar da forma como quiser (orientação a objetos, via funções, [...]), que irá funcionar. Isso, em alguns casos, pode acabar desorganizando o seu código.

Se você procura uma framework MVC, sugiro que use o Sails.

> **[Sails](https://sailsjs.com/)**